# NodeJS/ExpressJS production deployment

Tags: express, deployment, build, production-environment

OK, this may be a dumb question, or entirely unnecessary, but I'll risk sounding like an idiot to know for sure.

I have a prototype application frontend using Angular2 and a backend (really just a RestAPI server) using Node/Express.  I have the frontend stuff building/minifying/browserfying etc. for production deployment.

Is there anything that is typically done to the backend server to do the same?  Bundling all the JS files and minifying them or anything?

I can't seem to find anything about it without it including steps for using the express server for views/content.  In this prototype, ExpressJS is ONLY a RestAPI server, the frontend will be deployed to a separate web server.  It may be moot to look for this, since it's not going to be that large of a system, but I'm really curious.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I've been wondering the same thing.  My reason is that I find it hard believe that I must copy +6K files (at 65mb) from node_modules to my server in order to deploy.  There are a ton of package.json and README.md files in there.

Comment: Nope I haven't been able to find a solution, or guide for doing something like this.  I mean, it's completely feasible to just minify each file, but that's still a lot of files.